# How can I update an canvas without redrawing every element?

Tags: tkinter

Let's say I have an canvas, it has some kind of background drawn out of tkinter shapes, and on top I'm moving a circle around.

Is it possible to redraw just the circle, and not redraw the background every time?

Example code:

```
import  Tkinter

class gui(Tkinter.Tk):  

    def draw_background(self):
        self.canvas.create_oval(0,0, 500, 500, fill = 'black')

    def draw_circle(self,x, y):
        self.canvas.create_oval(x,y, x+10,y+10, fill = 'green')



    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.guiHeight = 800
        self.guiWidth = 800
        self.initialise()

    def animation(self):

        self.x = self.x +1%100
        self.y = self.y +1%100

        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.draw_background()      
        self.draw_circle(self.x, self.y)

        self.after(100,self.animation)

    def initialise(self):
        self.title('traffic')

        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, height = self.guiHeight, width = self.guiWidth)
        self.draw_background()      
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.after(100, self.animation)
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = gui(None)
```

This code will achieve exactly what I want it to do. A green dot moves toward the bottom right corner, and displays it self on top of the background circle.

However, it seems wasteful to tell it redraw the background image every time (Imagine if there was a lot of calculation involved in drawing the background) Is it possible to display at transparent layer on top of it, and just redraw the layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move any item on a canvas with the [move](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.move-method) method. You can also [delete](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method) any one item and redraw it. Neither of those require redrawing any other objects.

When you create an item, an ID is returned which you can give to the move or delete methods.

```
self.circle_id = self.canvas.create_oval(x,y, x+10,y+10, fill = 'green')
...
# move the circle 10 pixels in the x and y directions
self.canvas.move(self.circle_id, 10,10)
```

You can also give one or more elements a tag (actually, a list of tags), and then move or delete all of the elements with that tag in a single command as well:

```
self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill='green', tags=("circle",))
...
self.canvas.move("circle", 10, 10)
```

You can also compute all new coordinates for the circle and then update it with the [coords](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) method:

```
# make the upper-left corner 0,0 and the lower right 100,100
self.canvas.coords("circle", 0,0,100,100)
```