# is there a way to use an image as the background of the canvas without it getting earased every time an interval "delets" a part of the screen?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

1. I write a game in javascript and i set a background image. I use intervals in order to move the characteres, and every time I move the characters I need to delete the last character(a normal animation in canvas), so every time it delets the character it also delets the background image. Is there a way to make this image  as the actual background of the canvas, so it won't be deleted every time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update an canvas without redrawing every element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926491/how-can-i-update-an-canvas-without-redrawing-every-element)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **set a background image**?

```
function update(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.drawImage(background_image);

    //draw other game sprite here

}

setInterval(update, 30);
```

If that's what you mean by "setting a background image", you should still see your background image every refresh of your canvas. If you don't want to put **context.drawImage** in your code, then I will suggest making a CSS file to control your canvas' background. Solution's below:

Sample HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Sample CSS: (style.css)

```
#my_canvas{
    background-image: url('your_background_image.png');
}
```

I hope that solves your problem.